# How to separate a generated string in the console.log in JS

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while, console.log

I am hoping to put this question right. I am a total beginner, just for your info.

So, I do have this do **while loop code, that I found on w3s**:

```js
var text = "";
var i = 1;
do {
  text += "The number is " + i;
  i++;
}
while (i < 3);
```

I wanted to learn how it works, and **inserted the console.log**, like this.

```js
var text = "";
var i = 1;
do {
  text += "The number is " + i;
  i++;
  console.log(text);
}
while (i < 3);
```

**The console log shows me the following result:**
The number is 1
The number is 1The number is 2

**Question**
How could I console log the output that my results (The number is 1The number is 2) are not on the same line.
It is interesting to me to know whether I can give any command, so the the console log behaves differently, like
The number is 1
The number is 2
...

Thanks a lot, everybody! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new line character `\n`

```js
var text = "";
var i = 1;
do {
  text += "The number is " + i + '\n';
  i++;
  console.log(text);
}
while (i < 3);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!:))

Comment: @dmitriwd If the answer resolved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left